# How can I find out which Form trigger the script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to have my standalone script a common trigger(onFormSubmit trigger) for multiple forms and determine the which form triggered the script.

```
function myFunction() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm('FormID_1').onFormSubmit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm('FormID_2').onFormSubmit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm('FormID_3').onFormSubmit().create();
}

function onFormSubmit(e){
  Logger.log(e);
}
```

However the parameter e only has {authMode=FULL, response=FormResponse, triggerUid=......}, no FormId.

How can I know which form triggered the script?

Answer (score 1):

Please think of this as one of several answers. From your question, it is found that you can retrieve `triggerUid` from the parameter `e`. So how about saving `triggerUid` using PropertiesService? `triggerUid` is ID for each trigger. By using this ID, the form which is submitted can be retrieved.

When you use this sample script, at first, please run `myFunction()`, and submit using form. You can see the result at Stackdriver (View -> Stackdriver Logging). The form ID of form which was used can be retrieved.

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var FormID_1 = 'FormID_1';
  var FormID_2 = 'FormID_2';
  var FormID_3 = 'FormID_3';
  var form1 = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(FormID_1).onFormSubmit().create();
  var form2 = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(FormID_2).onFormSubmit().create();
  var form3 = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(FormID_3).onFormSubmit().create();
  var forms = {};
  forms[FormID_1] = form1.getUniqueId();
  forms[FormID_2] = form2.getUniqueId();
  forms[FormID_3] = form3.getUniqueId();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(forms);
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var forms = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  for (v in forms) {
    if (forms[v] == e.triggerUid) {
      console.log(v) // v is the form name which was submitted. You can see this at Stackdriver.
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference :

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

How about this? In this case, each form has each function. And each function calls `onFormSubmit(e)`.

```
function myFunction() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('form1').forForm('FormID_1').onFormSubmit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('form2').forForm('FormID_2').onFormSubmit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('form3').forForm('FormID_3').onFormSubmit().create();
}

function form1(e){
  onFormSubmit(e)
}

function form2(e){
  onFormSubmit(e)
}

function form3(e){
  onFormSubmit(e)
}

function onFormSubmit(e){
  Logger.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is an optional solution.I thought so before.However, considering the increase in maintenance costs, I think this method is not good.( 1. I will make mistakes easily when I need to delete some trigger since there is no name but a number    2.hard to tell someone who don't understand coding how to add or delete trigger )

Comment: The question is I have multiple forms need to do the same thing onFormSubmit. Initially I copy the same code to each form's editor and set the trigger manually. Lately I found this solution has a problem that when I need to update few codes I need to open each form's editor to modify.So I want to make a change to reduce maintenance cost, do you have any good iead?@Tanaike

Comment: @Zhiyong I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I don't think it is a good idea. 1.I need formId to do the job in my functions.  2.using multiple functions cause reduplicate, there will be too many lines to maintenance.

Comment: @Zhiyong I'm sorry for the inconvenience. How about using the identification value for each form? When the response is received, it identifies each form from title and item name which is included in the parameter ``e``.